# php update record doesn't work due to lookup variable somehow being dropped

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

So I'm having a challenge with a subscription system that I've been building.
I'm using a simple login php page to validate the username and password of the user against the DB,  once authenticated the script creates a secure session and calls the edit_subscription.php file and passes the ID of the user through the Url.

The edit_subscription.php file takes the ID and pulls the user info using MYsql
and loads their info into a form.  The user can then edit or modify their subscription details and press the submit button to update the DB.

Everything works except the mysql Update back to the DB.
I've managed to narrow the problem down to the ID variable
If I hardcode the variable into the update command it works and the db is updated
If I hardcode the ID into a variable used in the update command, it works up to a point.  if I move that hardcoded variable in front of line 42 the update command will no longer work.

I think it's something to do with the post command, but even when I load the old ID into a hidden form and try to have it repost for the update command it still doesn't work and treats the variable as if it's empty.

I've tried for hours to get this working, and just can seem to get it going.

anyone have any suggestions pertaining to specifically this issue
(please don't comment of security or, best practices unless it relates specifically to the issue described  thanks)

```
    <? 
$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['ID']);

$username="****";
$database="****";
$host="****";
$pass ="****";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `****`.`****` WHERE  `Subscriber ID` = '$id' LIMIT 1");
$name_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Name");
$address1_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Address 1");
$address2_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Address 2");
$city_old=mysql_result($result,0,"City");
$prov_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Prov");
$postal_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Postal");
$country_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Country");
$email_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Email");
$qty_old=mysql_result($result,0,"qty");
$status_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Status");
$ezine_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Ezine");
$mailout_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Mailout");
$password_old=mysql_result($result,0,"Password");

$nameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = "";

$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$address1=$_POST['address1'];
$address2=$_POST['address2'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$province=$_POST['prov'];
$postal=$_POST['postal'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$password=$_POST['password'];    
$mailout=$_POST['mailout'];
$ezine=$_POST['ezine'];
$status="Subscribed";
$qty=$_POST['qty'];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $passwordErr = "* Password is required";
     }

     if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
         $nameErr = "* Name is required";
     } else {
         $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
             $nameErr = "* Invalid Characters"; 
        }
     }

    if(isset($_POST['mailout'])){}
else{
    $mailout="NO";
}   
if(isset($_POST['ezine'])){}
else{
    $ezine="NO";
}     
     if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
         $emailErr = "* Email is required";
     } else {
         $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
         if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
             $emailErr = "* Invalid email"; 
         } 
     }  
    if($name != NULL AND $nameErr == ""){
          if($email != NULL AND $emailErr == ""){
              if($password != NULL AND $passwordErr == ""){
mysql_query("UPDATE `Subscribers` SET
      `Name` ='$name',
      `Email` =  '$email',
      `Address 1` =  '$address1',
      `Address 2` =  '$address2',
      `City` =  '$city',
      `Prov` =  '$province',
      `Postal` =  '$postal',
      `Country` =  '$country',
      `Password` =  '$password',
      `qty` =  '$qty',
      `Status` =  '$status',
      `Mailout` =  '$mailout',
      `Ezine` =  '$ezine',
      WHERE `Subscriber ID` = $id");
mysql_close();
                 echo ("<p align=\"center\"><font color=\"red\">Thank you for updating your subscription, you should receive an email confirmation shortly</font></p>");

              }
          }
     }   
}
function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="11%" align="right">Name</td>
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="47%"><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name_old;?>">
        <font color="red"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></font></td>
      <td width="39%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="checkbox" name="ezine" value="YES" 
            <?  if($ezine_old =="YES"){echo "checked";}  ?>>
        Subscribe by email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="11%" align="right">Address 1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="47%"><input type="text" name="address1" value="<?php echo $address1_old;?>"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="checkbox" name="mailout" value="YES" <?  if($mailout_old =="YES"){echo "checked";}  ?>>
        Subscribe by Post&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="11%" align="right">Address 2</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="47%"><input type="text" name="address2" value="<?php echo $address2_old;?>"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="text" name="qty" value="<?php echo $qty_old;?>" size="5">
        # of copies.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">City</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city_old;?>"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Province</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prov" value="<?php echo $prov_old;?>" >
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Postal</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="postal"value="<?php echo $postal_old;?>"  ></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Country</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $country_old;?>" ></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Email</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email_old;?>">
        <font color="red"><?php echo $emailErr;?></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Password</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password_old;?>">
        <font color="red"> <?php echo $passwordErr;?></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><img src="images/shim.png" width="20" height="20" /></td>
      <td><input type="Submit" ></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO

Comment: yeah thanks.. but as i mentioned... commenting on how I should use a different connection method doesn't help the issue that the variable  empties itself halfway through my script.  you should get a gold star for being so helpfull

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma after
    `Ezine` = '$ezine' ,

Remove it. Also you shall also use mysqli extension or PDO sql . `mysql_` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there is a lot wrong with that code.. however to satisfy your question here is the simple answer:

You left an extra comma in your update statement.

```
`Ezine` =  '$ezine',
```

In the future try always checking if the query went through.

```
$result = mysql_query(..);
if($result) {
    // it worked
} else {
    // it failed
    echo mysql_error(); // or mysqli_error($link); or $link->error, etc.
}
```

Best of luck

Comment: the comma after $ezine is irrelevant and has no effect on the update string.

Comment: Except that when I tried the query in my own DB it failed with the comma. I gave you a solution on how to debug. Why will you not post the SQL error? Just change `mysql_query` to `print` and make it print the query to the screen. Then copy and paste it into your DB and you will have your answer.